# AngularJS using service variable with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I want to be able to determine which directive is displayed based on a variable from a shared service. This is what I have so far.

main.html

```
<character-select ng-if="stateChangeService.playerState === 'characterSelect'"></character-select>
<fight-display ng-if="stateChangeService.playerState === 'fight'"></fight-display>
```

service

```
  angular
    .module('outerZone')
    .service('stateChangeService', stateChangeService);

  function stateChangeService() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.playerState = 'characterSelect';

  }
```

Currently when I load the page, nothing displays. The service is injected into both the character-select directive and the fight-display directive as well as the MainController. Any ideas?

Comment: can  you post more code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way your view knows anything about your service. You should assign your service to context.

```
angular.module('outerZone').controller('MainController', MainController)

MainController.$inject = ['stateChangeService'];
function MainController(stateChangeService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.stateChangeService = stateChangeService;
}

<body ng-controller="MainController as mc">
    <character-select ng-if="mc.stateChangeService.playerState === 'characterSelect'"></character-select>
    <fight-display ng-if="mc.stateChangeService.playerState === 'fight'"></fight-display>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use those variable on view/HTML which are bounded to `$scope` or `this`(while using controllerAs pattern). You should expose your `service/factory/constant` on view, OR rather better way would write a getter for accessing particular variable from service. Its best practice to expose relevant matter from service. There after you could call that getter from view like `getPlayerState()`

**HTML**

```
<character-select ng-if="getPlayerState() === 'characterSelect'"></character-select>
<fight-display ng-if="getPlayerState() === 'fight'"></fight-display>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(stateChangeService, $scope){

   $scope.getPlayerState = function(){
      return stateChangeService.playerState;
   }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

View in  Angular can access variables in current $scope or parent scopes.
so you have to assign service to current $scope or $rootScope.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('app')
  
  // your service 
 .service('myService', myServiceFunction);
      function myServiceFunction(){
        this.data = function(){ return true;    };
      };
     


  // your controller
  .controller('myController', myControllerFunction);

  // inject $scope and service
  myControllerFunction.$inject=['$scope','myService'];

  function myControllerFunction($scope, myService){
    //attatch service to current scope
    $scope.myService = myService;  
  };
  
})();
```

```html
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="myController">
{{myService.data()}}
</div>
```